# UIImageView and UIButton Background Image turns black when loaded in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I have two UIImageViews I am adding to different scenes, and they are turning black. If I change the image name and re-upload them to image.xcassets, the problem is fixed for a some builds but then it appears again.

Screenshots

[image]
[image]

There should be a play button where the black box is, and the Score and Highscore underlined things should be white not black.

Score label image code

```
class GameOverScene : SKScene {

var scoreImgView : UIImageView!

override func didMoveToView(view : SKView) {
    //Score Image Label
    let scoreLabel2 = "scorez2.png"
    let scoreImage = UIImage(named: scoreLabel2)
    scoreImgView = UIImageView(image: scoreImage)
    scoreImgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 1.8, height: view.frame.size.height / 8)
    scoreImgView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 3.2)
    scoreImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(scoreImgView)

}
}
```

Retry Button/Play Button Code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var restartButton : UIButton!
var retryButton : UIImage = UIImage(named: "playbutton.png")!

 override func didMoveToView(view : SKView) {

    //Restart Button
    restartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3.2, height: 50))
    restartButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.25)
    restartButton.setImage(retryButton, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    restartButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    restartButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Restart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(restartButton)
}
}
```

Edit:
All the images are in Images.xcassets. Is this the wrong place to put them?
[image]

EDIT:
The images show up fine on an iPhone 5s.

Comment: Still can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .png and it seems to be working fine now. I'll update if it breaks again.